# How to convert Readdata ,Writedata from mainDrive to separated Class in Java

Tags: java

I have Java program work correctly. Just I need to convert writeData and readData Methods from MainDrive to separated Class.

The MainDrive

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String CARS_FILE = "C:\\data\\cars.dat";

        RandomAccessFile carsFile = null ;

        ArrayList <Cars> carsList = new ArrayList <Cars>() ;

        try
        {
            carsFile = new RandomAccessFile(CARS_FILE, "rw");
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("n IOException occurred while attempting to allocate the Cars File.") ;
        }

        Cars car = new Cars(1000) ;
        carsList.add(car) ;
        car = new Cars(2000) ;
        carsList.add(car) ;
        car = new Cars(3000) ;
        carsList.add(car) ;

        // writing to File
        System.out.println("\nWrite cars List to the file.\n");

        try
        {
            carsFile.seek(0); 

            for (Cars itemObj : carsList) 
            {
                writeData( carsFile, itemObj);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An IOException occurred while attempting to write data to " + carsFile + ".") ;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("A generic Exception occurred while attempting to write data to " + carsFile + ".") ;
        }


        // Reading from File

        System.out.println("\nReading from file:\n");

        try
        {
            Cars readRecord = new Cars() ; 

            carsFile.seek(0); // Be sure that the file pointer points to the first byte in the file.

            while ( true ) 
            {
                readData( carsFile, readRecord );

                System.out.println(readRecord.getNumber());
            }
        }
        catch ( EOFException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Reached EOF on " + carsFile + " : " + e.toString() + ".") ;
        }

        catch ( IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Probably reached EOF on " + carsFile + " : " + e.getMessage() + ".") ;
        }

        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("An exception occurred reading " + carsFile + " : " + e.getMessage() + ".") ;
        }



        // close the file
        try
        {
            carsFile.close() ;
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An IOException occurred while attempting to close " + carsFile + " : " + e.getMessage() + ".") ;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("A generic Exception occurred while attempting to close " + carsFile + " : " + e.getMessage() + ".") ;
        }


    }
// ReadData Method
    private static void readData(RandomAccessFile carsFile, Cars readRecord) throws IOException, EOFException, Exception {
        readRecord.setNumber(carsFile.readInt());

    }
// WriteData Method
    private static void writeData(RandomAccessFile carsFile, Cars itemObj) throws IOException, EOFException, Exception{
        carsFile.writeInt(itemObj.getNumber());


    }

}
```

and The Cars Class

```
public class Cars {

    private int Number ;



    public Cars(){
        setNumber(0);
    }
    public Cars(int number) {
        setNumber(number);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        Number = number;
    }

}
```

My Question, How to convert writeData and readData to separated Class for example DataAccessFile

```
public class DataAccessFile{

writeData() method ;
readData() method ;


}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and include only the releavant code. Plus, SO is not a code refactoring service.

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow = this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic shape of your class would be something like

```
public class DataAccessFile{
    private  RandomAccessFile carsfile;

    Public DataAccessFile(RandomAccessFile carsFile){
        this.carsFile = carsFile;
     ....
    }
    public void writeData(Car car){
     ....
    }
    public Car readData(){
     .....
    }
}
```

You could also add methods to open and close carsfile or include the open in the constructor in which case the constructor could take a String argument containing the file path and name.

Comment: Thank you redge. That's will help me a lot